# popUpTo nested navigation graph ID not popping to startDestination

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm trying to use [`popUpTo`](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop) as part of configuring an action in androidx navigation to make sure the back button on the next screens returns to the specified fragment ID.

The problem is the fragment I want to navigate back to is defined as the `startDestination` of a [nested graph](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-nested-graphs#include). I would expect to be able to specify the ID of the nested graph in `popUpTo`, so that I don't have to link directly to a child fragment's ID, which I understand to be bad practice, if even not an error.

However, the only way to get the behavior I desire is by setting `popUpTo` to the ID defined as `startDestination` in the nested graph. Specifying the nested graph ID instead jumps over the fragments defined therein.

I could not find specific guidance on how to use `popUpTo` with nested graphs. Could anyone provide more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would expect to be able to specify the ID of the nested graph in popUpTo, so that I don't have to link directly to a child fragment's ID, which I understand to be bad practice, if even not an error.

This should work correctly. If this does not work, it means something else is going wrong.

In my case, it turned out that elsewhere in the codebase the `backQueue` of `NavController` was manipulated manually (`.clear()`) was called.

After removing the offending code, I could update my `popUpTo` to refer to the nested graph ID, and the backstack got cleared as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue with safe args where `popUpTo` references the nested graph's ID.

***settings.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    app:startDestination="@id/settingsFragment">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/log_in" />
    <include app:graph="@navigation/discovery" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
        android:name="com.example.SettingsFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_settingsFragment_to_log_in"
            app:destination="@id/log_in"
            app:popUpTo="@id/discovery"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

Generated `SettingsFragmentDirections.actionSettingsFragmentToLogIn()` fails with the abovementioned exception.

I ended up [using ID](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#id) for the navigation, like

```
findNavController().popBackStack(destinationId = R.id.discovery, inclusive = true)
findNavController().navigate(resId = R.id.log_in)
```